# IOS - Vertically Align the Back Button in NavigationBar

Tags: ios5, uinavigationbar

I newbie in iOS Programming.
i Have a cutom navigation bar that have 70 px height and i want that back button and Title is vertically align to middle.

I alredy done with the navbar title.
But i dont have any idea how to vertically align the back button to middle.

thanks.

[image: Navigation Bar]

Comment: check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250389/ios-7-custom-back-indicator-image-position/45184644#45184644

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 5 you can customise the position of the back buttons of all of your navigation bars with this magic incantation:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-10 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-10 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

This will move the back button 10 pixels upwards.

A good place to put this code is in your application delegate's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.

Or if you just want to customise one button:

```
[myBackButton setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-10 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[myBackButton setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-10 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

More information:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score -3):

Set the back bar button's **center.y** to the imageview's **height/2**.

Comment: i didn't get it.. a sample maybe usefull