# iOS 7: Custom Back Indicator Image Position

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar

I'm having trouble setting properly a custom back indicator image. The indicator is not centered!

Here is a pic:

[image: Screenshot showing non-centered custom back indicator image]

I'm setting the indicator image in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back"];
   [UINavigationBar appearance].backIndicatorImage = image;
   [UINavigationBar appearance].backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = image;

   return YES;
}
```

How can I center it?

p.s I've already read this [Custom back indicator image in iOS 7 not vertically centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684661/custom-back-indicator-image-in-ios-7-not-vertically-centered), but actually it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That happens because you are just changing the image source of the Back Indicator in your UINavigationView, and not the frame as well.
See, when the UINavigationView is created, the Back Indicator's frame is set to hold the size of the default iOS 7 back button image. The default back button image is bigger than yours, and that's why it looks not aligned.

To fix that you have to reset the Back Indicator's Frame to hold the size of your image. Another option is to create a UIButton with the right frame size and image and assign to a UIBarButtonItem. Then you can replace the backBarButtonItem from your UINavigationItem with the new UIBarButtonItem you created.

Comment: Thanks man for the useful explanation! But how can I reset the back indicator's frame?

Comment: Actually, you would have to create a new UIBarButtonItem with your UIButton that has the new frame and image and assign to your UINavigationItem. Although, you can do something a little more fast and easy. Make your back button's image the same size of the default iOS 7 back button's image. You don't need to actually stretch your buttons, just create a image with the same size of the iOS default back button, and put your button in the center of it. This way your button's image will have spaces on top and bottom that will make it the same size of the default button. Just some photoshop work =)

Comment: Or, if you still want to create a a custom UIBarButtonItem, here is a good example: http://www.appgroup.co.uk/adding-a-uibarbuttonitem-with-a-custom-image/

Comment: The easier the better. So I used Sketch App to make the image fits the back indicator view's size. It works perfectly!

Comment: I have found that images with height 17px (34 @2x, 51 @3x) are shown centered vertically, but this is just from observations

Comment: I have found that 23px is vertically finy iOS9.2

Answer (score 20):

```
 UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 2, 0);
 UIImage *backArrowImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back"] imageWithAlignmentRectInsets:insets];

 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:backArrowImage];
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:backArrowImage];
```

Comment: This technique works, but strangely I needed to add an inset to the bottom, to move the image down.

Comment: This seems to work for vertical positioning, but not horizontal positioning. How do I adjust the horizontal positioning?

Comment: In Swift it works for horizontal, tho I'm setting the mask and backArrowImage first not sure if it has meaning.

`let backArrow: UIImage = UIImage.whiteBackArrow.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal).withAlignmentRectInsets(.init(top: 0, left: -10, bottom: 0, right: 0))`

Answer (score 6):

This is how I dealt with the problem using Appearance API and is working great. 
When changing backButtonBackgroundImage image is automatically stretched across barButtonItem so we must resize it back to original using **resizableImageWithCapInsets:**.
To position it inside barButtonItem we then use **imageWithAlignmentRectInsets** to add caps around it. Then just assign it using **setBackButtonBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics**.

Just play with the numbers and you will find the right position.

```
int imageSize = 24;
UIImage *barBackBtnImg = [[[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, imageSize, 0, 0)] imageWithAlignmentRectInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, 0, -10)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:barBackBtnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me in Swift 2.1. iOS 9.2.1. (Xcode 7.2) on iPhone in portrait Mode. I have tested it on the simulators iPhone 5 and 6+ and it also worked.

```
import UIKit

class EVEMainNaviVC: UINavigationController
{
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = APP_BACKGROUND_COLOR
    self.setupAppNaviagtionBar()
}


private func setupAppNaviagtionBar()
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
    { () -> Void in
        self.navigationBar.setHeight(55.0)
        self.navigationBar.translucent        = false
        self.navigationBar.alpha              = 1.0
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor       = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let newBackButtonImageInset                         = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -6, 0)
        let newBackButtonImage                              = UIImage(named: "back")?.imageWithAlignmentRectInsets(newBackButtonImageInset)
        self.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage               = newBackButtonImage
        self.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = newBackButtonImage
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = CUSTOM_BUTTON_COLOR
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is when setting the back button on an actual navigation bar instance. The problem described in the question arises when trying to achieve the same using UINavigationBar apparance to set this up globally.

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest solution I have ever seen. Just three things.

1. Override `UINavigationBar` and use it in your `UINavigationController`

   ```
   let navigationController = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: NavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)
   navigationController.viewControllers = [viewController]
   ```
2. Setup your indicator images:

   ```
   backIndicatorImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "back")
   backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "back")
   ```
3. Implement `layoutSubviews` in your custom `UINavigationBar` class.

   ```
   override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()

       subviews.forEach { (view) in
           if let imageView = view as? UIImageView {
               if imageView.image == backIndicatorImage || imageView.image == backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage {
                   view.frame.origin.y = floor((frame.height - view.frame.height) / 2.0)
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

That is all. :)

Comment: Question was about appearance, not about using custom classes

Answer (score 0):

My goal was to position the back button image without meddling with the subviews of the `UINavigationItem`. So, what I did was to create an extension for `UIImage` that adds a padding around of the image.

```swift
extension UIImage {
    public func imageWith(padding: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIImage {
        let origin = CGPoint(x: padding.left, y: padding.top)
        let sizeWithPadding = CGSize(width: padding.left + size.width + padding.right, height: padding.top + size.height + padding.bottom)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sizeWithPadding, false, 0.0)
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))

        let imageWithPadding = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() ?? self
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return imageWithPadding
    }
}
```

For example: if you want to move the image to the top you add the corresponding padding to the bottom.
`.imageWith(padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 2, right: 0))`